# Using a cloned git repository in XCode

Tags: xcode, git, repository, project, cloning

I have cloned my git repository on XCode, but now I want to edit it : since I am in a team that uses different IDE and OS, my cloned repository contains only source code. How can I create an xcode project using that repository? I have created a project in the same folder of the repository and than dragged the source code in it, but only the default files (main.cpp)of the new created project work with "Source Control".

Comment: Did you try to right-click from the `Project Navigator` in XCode and select `Add files to "ProjectName"`? Your copied files are simply not visible in XCode, this action will make your project aware of these files